# SLIM Application error. Code 8: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, slim

I'm currently working in a mobile application (Front-end) which brings some data through a Php Slim backend from a MySQL database using PDO. This   (Back-end) was developed by a team mate and works like a charm on his computer.

There's a GET route which is supposed to return some JSON data:

```
$app->get('/users', function () {
   require_once  'controllers/User.php';
   $user = new User();
   $user->setJsonMode(true);
   $user->setJoin('default');
   $user->setSelect('user_id, user.role_id, role, name,
                     userName, email, picture, user.last_update');
   echo $user->select();
});
```

The 'User' Controller as all of them, inherit from 'CtrlDB' controller.

If I try to access '**api/users**' I get:

Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Array to string conversion
File: /home/shy-n/projects/tienda/api/controllers/CtrlDB.php
Line: 32

The line 32 is located at the CtrlDB constructor:

```
public function __construct($table,$fields,$idProperty,$relations) {
    $dsn = DB_ENGINE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8';
    try {
        $this->db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
         $response = $this->response("error","Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage(),null);
         echo $response;
         exit;
    }

    $this->table = $table;
    $this->idProperty = $idProperty;
    $this->fields = $fields;
    $this->relations = $relations;
    $this->start = 0;
    $this->limit = 25;
    $this->select = "`".implode("`, `",$fields)."`";
}
```

In "**echo $response**" I get the error, and I have no clue what's going on.

He uses WAMP server with php 5.5.12

I'm using Arch Linux 64 Bits with LAMP with php 5.6.5. I have enabled both extensions
**mysqli.so** and **pdo_mysql.so** in my php.ini file.

I have imported the database used with phpmyAdmin, containing the same registers as my friend in the back-end.

In spite of all of this, he can get the JSON data accessing the /users route, but I can't.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
  echo $response;
```

try

```
  echo json_encode($response);
```

you shouldn't be echoing out arrays

Comment: Well, yeah. I just used print_r($response) and seeing the catched PDO exception error, it turned out to be our different DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD configuration... Communication issues, finally solved the problem.